# Process SSAS tabular model from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

So I've installed AMO and created the following console application:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular;


namespace procesarCuboSSAST
{


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string ConnectionString = "Data source=SERVER\\BI";


                using (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server server = new Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Server())
                {
                    server.Connect(ConnectionString);

                    Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.Database Db = server.Databases["TestModel"];     //Connect to the DB

                    Model m = Db.Model;


                  m.RequestRefresh(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType.Full);
                    m.SaveChanges();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to close this console window.");
                Console.ReadLine();



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Write(e.Message.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to close this console window.");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting error: **"object reference not set to an instance of an object"**

I can correctly list the databases and models in the SSAS instance with

```
 foreach (Database db in server.Databases) 
                { 
                    Console.WriteLine("Properties for database {0}:", db.Name); 
...
```

My server is SSAS 2014 Enterprise (tabular) (12.0.5000.0)

Comment: You have posted the error message that's a start. Now please indicate which line it occurs on.

Comment: m.RequestRefresh

Comment: OK this means `m` is not properly instantiated. You just need to run this in debug mode and inspect variables as you step through and find out where it's failing

Answer (score 1):

What compatibility level is the Tabular model that you're attempting to process?  The `Model` class is only for Tabular models at level 1200 or above.  The `Database` class will let you view models at a lower compatibility level, but not modify them, which is why you can list the SSAS databases on the instance but not process them.  The links below contain addition details on these classes.

[Model Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.model?view=sqlserver-2016)

[Database Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.database?view=sqlserver-2016)